# SE site for "interesting mathematics"

Tags: discussion, area51

It was recently asked on the MO meta whether it was ok to post interesting bit of mathematics one had stumbled across on MO (http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1554/how-to-use-mo-as-a-multiplicator/).

The replies seem to generally be along the lines of "no, please don't do this, unless you really have a question you want answered".

Similarly, here on MSE, we occasionally have people asking if they can do this (since the FAQ says they can), and the consensus seems to be that this should at least be kept to a minimum.

On the MO meta, however, someone mentioned that it would be nice to have an SE-structured site for such things, ie a site where one can post interesting bits of mathematics one finds various places and which seem like they might also be interesting to other mathematicians (so ones that are probably not known to most mathematicians).

I have started this meta thread to ask if people think this will be doable (both in terms of getting such a site approved and in terms of moderating it).

One issue with moderation such a site is at what level one wants the mathematics, and how to make sure it does not get cluttered with a bunch of things that are well-known to anyone at some level.

Another concern would also be whether such a site is really suited for the Q&A format, as it is not clear what a good answer to such a bit of mathematics should be (maybe interesting applications of that bit of mathematics?).

Comment: Somewhat related questions: [Would having an area to publish non-questions be useful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/would-having-an-area-to-publish-non-questions-be-useful) and
[Does our site need a blog like a few sites on the network have?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/does-our-site-need-a-blog-like-a-few-sites-on-the-network-have)

Comment: I'm not really sure about the suitability of the Q&A format, but should that be the case, everyone can propose new SE sites at http://area51.stackexchange.com/. Alternatively, either the mentioned blog or something like the non-existent [fourth place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/146482 "The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff") I feature-requested some years ago might suit...

Comment: Start a sub-reddit? That seems to fit the bill better than SE does to me.

Comment: I think such a SE site would be horrendous. I mean, one person's "interesting" is another person's worst nightmare of boringness, piled on top of more boredom boredom boredom *boredom*. We all know this - we are mathematicians, explorers in what is universally acknowledged as the most boring jungle known to man (and yet we find it beautiful...). I *do* like the blog idea though.

Answer (score 23):

This seems like this is the sort of thing [blogoverflow](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) was designed for. SE will host blogs for SE communities if the community is interested and seems energetic and organized enough to keep one going. Check out the [mathematica](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/) and [TeX](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) blogs for examples of successful blogs.

As someone who used to be part of an active [group blog](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/) about mathematics and hasn't completely given up on it, I can tell you that blogging is very rewarding but also very time consuming. If you have the energy to write up some interesting math once or twice a month, and can find a half dozen SE contributors who will do the same, I think that would make a great blog!

There is a year old [meta-question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/does-our-site-need-a-blog-like-a-few-sites-on-the-network-have) about setting up a math blog for the site. People were positive, but no one committed to it. If I were you, I would ask a meta question whose title was "Would you post to a math community blog at least once a month?"

Comment: so can we set up a community math blog

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it could be technically doable as a blog, and I think that it would be nice to see math tidbits, as opposed to math questions. I am thinking about something like *
Professor Stewart's Cabinet of Mathematical Curiosities / Hoard of Mathematical Treasures*

I am not bothered by the level of the mathematics in the blog, as long as each post has a tag stating its "maths level"; however I would warn too people that such a blog must be nurtured, and this means that several people must commit to write regularly. (Don't look at me! I do have a math blog, but it is in Italian, of course)